# Converting 3-band raster of a topo map into Unique Values with Colormap or by Reclassifying using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-conversion, basemap, colormap

[image: Top left: This is the 3-band raster with unsigned 8-bit pixels. I need to change it to a single band raster with a signed pixel type so I can reclassify unique values like in the top right.]

I'm using a 1998 USGS topo map for a geologic map base in ArcMap 10.5.1. Right now, the topo raster is in 3-bands with an unsigned 8-bit pixel type. Strictly for cartographic reasons, I need to strip away the green from the topo, and keep the other colors. In order to do that, I converted the raster to an 8-bit signed pixel type by using Copy Raster. Then, I needed to convert the 3-band raster into a single-band raster. For that I used Image Analysis and made the raster grayscale. I can then build an attribute table for the new raster and can apply unique values to the pixels. However, I'm having trouble correlating the values in the new raster to the colors in the original raster. I think I need to build a colormap, but don't know how.